# How to assign a `const char *GetVersion()` (from a third-party library) to a variable?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

How to assign a variable to the value of `const char *GetVersion()`?

I am using a third-party library which states that `const char *GetVersion()` is available. The below code compiles successfully:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "ThirdPartyLibrary.h"

int main()
{
    const char *GetVersion();
}
```

How to assign `const char *GetVersion()` to a variable?

**Update**

> char const *GetVersion()
>
> The version of the Application manual
>   interface that has loaded the running extension. This version is
>   distinct from the API version, which is documented in Macros , below.

Comment: `std::string s = Function();`?

Comment: You mean `const char* name = Function();` ?

Comment: The same way you would do it with a double or int function.

Comment: The `*` is next to `Function()`, that is `*Function`. I tried `const char* name = Function();` as well as `std::string s = Function();` and got a `'Function': identifier not found` error.

Comment: Then Function doesn't exist!

Comment: Please quote *verbatim* what the third party library says about Function.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many spaces there are between the * and any of the other components.

Comment: Please also quote (verbatim, in the body of the question) any compiler messages you are getting.

Comment: `std::string myversion = GetVersion();`

Comment: @n.m. I updated the post with the documentation content

Comment: It looks like you should be able to use it normally just like you have tried. Make sure you are including the correct header file.

Comment: @n.m. Got the variable assignment to work,  Visual Studio was missing the link to the definition and I wasn't using the namespace. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code compiles since the compiler understands

```
const char *Function();
```

as being a *function prototype*.

---

First of all, read the documentation. It looks like you can simply write

```
const char* my_variable = Function();
```

But do check if you need to release any memory. (My hunch is that you don't given the return type is a `const`, but perhaps you need to call back into that library passing `my_variable` as the parameter).

Answer (score 2):

> How to assign `const char *GetVersion()` to a variable?

I'd suggest to immediately safely store the raw C-style string pointer returned by your C-interface function to a `std::string` object:

```
std::string version = GetVersion();
```

It's much better/safer/more convenient in **C++** to manage strings using proper string *classes* than using C-style raw pointers.

You should also read your function documentation, to find out if you have to *release* the memory pointed by the returned `const char*`, or if this is not required.